# How can we override the constructor while still using the `class` keyword?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming, metaclass, constructor-overloading

Two notable ways to create a class are shown below:

```
class Klass:
    pass

Klass = type("Klass", tuple(), dict())
```

I would like to  override the constructor (`__call__`) while still using the `class` keyword instead of doing something else, like directly calling `type`. I really do want to override (`__call__`), not `__init__`

My failed attempts are shown below:

### Attempt 1

```
class Foo:
    @classmethod
    def __call__(*args):
        print("arr har")
        return super(type(args[0]), args[0]).__call__(*args)

instance = Foo()
# did not print "arr har"
```

### Attempt 2

```
class BarMeta(type):
    def __call__(*args):
        print("hello world")
        return super(type(args[0]), args[0]).__call__(*args[1:])
```

- ### Attempt 2A

  ```
  class Bar:
      __metaclass__ = BarMeta

  instance = Bar()
  # did not print "hello world"
  ```
- ### Attempt 2B

  ```
  Baz = BarMeta("Baz", tuple(), dict())
  instance = Baz()
  # Did print "hello world," but we weren't able to use the `class` keyword to create `Baz`
  ```

Comment: But `__call__` is not he constructor, `__new__` is. If you want to override `__call__` all you have to do is override `__call__`

Comment: Attempt 2A would work if you were using python 2. In python 3, the syntax for defining a metaclass is `class Bar(metaclass=BarMeta):`.

Comment: @DeepSpace But `__call__` calls `__new__`, not the other way around. `instance = Klass()` is the same as `instance = Klass.__call__()` or `instance = type(Klass).__call__(Klass)`

Comment: Also, I (and apparently at least 2 other people) had a hard time understanding your question. It would've been a good idea to start by explicitly stating what you want to do, i.e. "I want `Bar()` to print 'arr har'".

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon `__call__` does not call `__new__`. The only thing `__call__` does is make **instances** of the class callable. That's all.

Comment: @DeepSpace `type.__call__` does indeed call `__new__` followed by `__init__`. That's why we can create instances of a class by calling that class.

Comment: @Aran-Fey do you have an example of `__call__` calling `__new__`? I don't seem to be able to reproduce such a case

Comment: @DeepSpace `type.__call__` is really the only example. https://repl.it/repls/EvenSandyPress

Answer (score 0):

All credit does to [Aran-Fey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1222951/aran-fey), who posted the answer as a comment, instead of as an answer:

```
class BarMeta(type):
    def __call__(*args):
        print("hello world")
        return super(type(args[0]), args[0]).__call__(*args[1:])    

class Bar(metaclass=BarMeta):
    pass

instance = Bar()
```